# Which storage is good for read performance

Tags: azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I have a custom data file. Reading this file with high speed on my local computer. Reading speed is avarage is 0.5 ms in my tests(simple read operations with seeking). I want to use same operation on azure. Tried to use Blob Storage with following steps:

1. Create cloud storage account
2. Create blob client
3. Get container
4. Get blob reference
5. OpenRead stream

This steps takes approximatelly 10-15 seconds. It's a readonly file. What can i do for increse reading performance? What is the best storage for a large number of read operations. In this time reading speed is more important for me. I do not want to use data file with web/worker role. I must be on the cloud storage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would have to analyze your access patterns to debug this issue further. For example, OpenRead gives you a stream that is easy to work with, but its read-ahead buffering strategy might not be optimal if you are seeking within the file. By default, the stream will buffer 4MB at a time, but it has to discard this buffer if the caller seeks beyond that 4MB range. Depending on how much you read after each seek, you might want to reduce the [read-ahead buffer size](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.blob.icloudblob.streamminimumreadsizeinbytes.aspx) or use [DownloadRangeToStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.blob.icloudblob.downloadrangetostream.aspx) API directly. Or, if your blob is small enough, you can download it in one shot using [DownloadToStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.blob.icloudblob.downloadtostream.aspx) API and then handle it in memory.

I would recommend using [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) to watch what requests your application makes to Azure Storage and see whether that is the best approach for your scenario. If you see that each individual request is taking a long time, you can [enable Azure Storage Analytics](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-monitor-storage-account/) to analyze the E2E latency and Server latency for those requests. Please refer to the [Monitor, diagnose, and troubleshoot Microsoft Azure Storage](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-monitoring-diagnosing-troubleshooting/) article for more information on how to interpret Analytics data.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. My data need to read sequential. One way from zero to the end of file with seeking (not to end). First read of file is more slower. Can you prefer any documentation for storage specialized on blobs storage?

Comment: If it is sequential and you need the entire file, I would recommend downloading it in one shot using DownloadToStream. The last article I mentioned in the answer about diagnosing and troubleshooting is a very good read for investigating performance issues.

Comment: I dont need to read entire file. I want to read specific bytes. Steps: Read 10 bytes from position zero, goto position 200 and read 20 bytes, goto position 500 and read 3 bytes ... Jumping from position to position what a need to read. Next positions information is stored in current position readings. So i never known what positions am i read before the start reading of file.

Comment: If the blob is small enough, downloading it entirely could still perform better. If not, I would recommend looking at DownloadRangeToStream API, as it allows you to specify the range (offset and length) to download on every request. Please also make sure you enable Azure Storage Analytics so that you can see how much time each request takes.